# What configurations need to be set for a LAMP server for heavy traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

I was contracted to make a groupon-clone website for my client. It was done in PHP with MYSQL and I plan to host it on an Amazon EC2 server. My client warned me that he will be email blasting to about 10k customers so my site needs to be able to handle that surge of clicks from those emails. I have two questions:

1) Which Amazon server instance should I choose? Right now I am on a Small instance, I wonder if I should upgrade it to a Large instance for the week of the email blast?

2) What are the configurations that need to be set for a LAMP server. For example, does Amazon server, Apache, PHP, or MySQL have a maximum-connections limit that I should adjust?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, putting the static pages, the PHP and the DB on the same instance isn't the best route to take if you want a highly scalable system. That said, if the budget is low and high availablity isn't a problem then you may get away with it in practise.

One option, as you say, is to re-launch the server on a larger instance size for the period you expect heavy traffic. Often this works well enough. You problem is that you don't know the exact model of the traffic that will come. You will get a certain percentage who are at their computers when it arrives and they go straight to the site. The rest will trickle in over time. Having your client send the email whilst the majority of the users are in bed, would help you somewhat, if that's possible, by avoiding the surge.

If we take the case of, say, 2,000 users hitting your site in 10 minutes, I doubt a site that hasn't been optimised would cope, there's very likely to be a silly bottleneck in there. The DB is often the problem, a good sized in-memory cache often helps.

This all said, there are a number of architectural design and features provided by the likes of Amazon and GAE, that enable you, with a correctly designed back-end, to have to worry very little about scalability, it is handled for you on the most part.

If you split the database away from the web server, you would be able to put the web server instances behind an elastic load balancer and have that scale instances by demand. There also exist standard patterns for scaling databases, though there isn't any particular feature to help you with that, apart from database instances.

You might want to try [Amazon mechanical turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome), which basically lots of people who'll perform often trivial tasks (like navigate to a web page click on this, etc) for a usually very small fee. It's not a bad way to simulate real traffic.

That said, you'd probably have to repeat this several times, so you're better off with a load testing tool. And remember, you can't load testing a time-slicing instance with another time-slicing instance...